# Enable/ Disable button inside list view based on a value in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a listview which is populated using a stackpanel in wpf. I want to hidden pooja_name if status value in 0 else it will be visible.

```
<ListView x:Name="bookedlist" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="449" Margin="679,238,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#00828790" Background="Transparent" Focusable="False">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stackkk" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="#FFB0AEAE">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Pooja_name}" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Width="250"/>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="#FFB0AEAE">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Width="250"/>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="#FFB0AEAE">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" TextAlignment="Left" MouseLeftButtonDown="Star_function" Margin="5" Width="95"/>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Listview is populated using a modelclass

```
public class Booked
{
    public string Pooja_name { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status{ get; set; }
}
```

and a jsonarray

```
JArray bookedpoojalist = JArray.Parse(bookedval);
            List<Booked> booked = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Booked>>(bookedpoojalist.ToString());
            bookedlist.ItemsSource = booked;
```

Comment: You can use a converter achiving this
Control->Visibility->Binding->Status->Converter

Comment: Can you please give one example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That should work for you:
declare Converter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <StringToVisibility x:Key="StringToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

      <StackPanel x:Name="stackkk" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="#FFB0AEAE" Visibility="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Pooja_name}" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Width="250"/>
         </Border>
      </StackPanel>
```

Converter:

```
    public class StringToVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString()== "0")
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an error The resource StringToVisibilityConverter could not be resolved

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` to the `Border` or the `TextBlock` element:

```
<Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="#FFB0AEAE">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Pooja_name}" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Width="250"/>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```